# How do you correctly set up multi user rotation for a postgres rds db in aws?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Im setting up a db user in cdk like this:

```
    const serviceUser = new rds.DatabaseSecret(this, 'my-foo-service-user-secret', {
        username: 'my-foo-service-user',
        masterSecret: this.postgresDb.secret,
    });

    const myAttachedSecret = serviceUser.attach(this.postgresDb);
    this.postgresDb.addRotationMultiUser('my-foo-service-user-rotation', {
        secret: myAttachedSecret,
    });
```

My db has added the user:

```
        CREATE USER "my-foo-service-user";
```

(Master user is working with single user rotation btw)

First cloudwatch is telling me that the secret has been successfully created in secrets manager:

`Successfully put secret for ... and version ...`

The cloudwatch is telling me that it can't update the user:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 79, in lambda_handler
    set_secret(service_client, arn, token)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 168, in set_secret
    raise ValueError("Unable to log into database using current credentials for secret %s" % arn)
ValueError: Unable to log into database using current credentials for secret ...
```

I took a dig at the rotation lambda and from my understanding, "createSecret" only updates secrets manager, and its this line of code thats throwing up (setSecret method):

```
    # This ensures that the credential we are rotating is valid to protect against a confused deputy attack
    current_dict = get_secret_dict(service_client, arn, "AWSCURRENT")
    conn = get_connection(current_dict)
    if not conn:
        logger.error("setSecret: Unable to log into database using current credentials for secret %s" % arn)
        raise ValueError("Unable to log into database using current credentials for secret %s" % arn)
    conn.close()
```

It looks like a bug to me, but I can't find any opens issues on multi user postgres rotation so I am guessing that I am setting this up wrong. Anyone who can spot my error?

Comment: Have you set the password for `my-foo-service-user` in the DB? Use the one generated by Secrets Manager and visible in the console. Then rotation can start.

Comment: I don't want to do that manually because it breaks the purpose of fully automated development

Comment: You already need to manually create the user (`CREATE USER "my-foo-service-user";`), You could code a custom resource that looks up the password and creates a user with this password in your DB using the master password.

Comment: I solved it by accessing secret manager from my db patching step and one-time setting the password for the db user using the generated secret. So I am still fully automated, but it would be nice if the rotation lambda did this when creating the secret 1st time in secrets manager.